# Prisma query junction table

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a DB with two tables: races and languages, and a junction table races_languages.
The idea being that a race can speak multiple languages, and a language can be spoken by multiple races.

Here's the schema prisma's generated for me:

```
model Language {
  id              Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String         @unique
  races_languages RaceLanguage[]

  @@map("languages")
}

model Race {
  id              Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String         @unique
  races_languages RaceLanguage[] @relation("racesToraces_languages")

  @@map("races")
}

model RaceLanguage {
  race_id     Int
  language_id Int
  languages   Language @relation(fields: [language_id], references: [id])
  races       Race     @relation("racesToraces_languages", fields: [race_id], references: [id])

  @@id([race_id, language_id])
  @@map("races_languages")
}
```

So far I've managed to allow queries like this to work:

```
{
  races {
    id
    name
    races_languages {
      languages {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to allow GraphQL queries that look like this from what's above:

```
{
  races {
    id
    name
    languages {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to flatten the `races_languages` part? What if there's another field in `races_languages` that I want to keep so that it looks like this:

```
{
  races {
    id
    name
    languages {
      somethingFromRacesLanguages
      name
    }
  }
}
```

My resolver looks like this:

```
  Query: {
    races: (root, args, { db }) =>
      db.race.findMany({
        include: {
          races_languages: { include: { languages: true } },
        },
      }),
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to flatten the join/junction table, in your case the `RaceLanguage` table.

You would need to fetch the data via `include` as you do above and then flatten it in your application logic itself.

If you do not have extra columns, you can use Implicit many-to-many relationships in which Prisma handles the junction table automatically as described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations)